# Use ranged algorithm on custom container

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I want to upgrade my custom container to compatible with `std::ranges` algorithms such as `find_if` and others, like bellow

```
auto is_satisfy = [](CustomContainer::value_type x) { ... };
std::ranges::find_if(custom_container, is_satisfy);
// instead of std::find_if(custom_container.begin(), custom_container.end(), is_satisfy);
```

Signature of `std::ranges::find_if` like as

```
struct find_if_fn {
   template< ranges::input_range R,
            class Proj = std::identity,
            std::indirect_unary_predicate<std::projected<ranges::iterator_t<R>,
                                         Proj>> Pred >
   constexpr ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R>
   operator()( R&& r, Pred pred = {}, Proj proj = {} ) const
   {
       return (*this)(ranges::begin(r), ranges::end(r), std::ref(pred), std::ref(proj));
   }
};
```

What is the [input_range concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range) and how this feature is supported by my own custom container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the input_range concept

It is this:

> ```
> template<class T>
>   concept input_­range =
>     range<T> && input_­iterator<iterator_t<T>>;
> ```

In English, input_range is a range whose iterator is an input_iterator. The range concept on the other hand is:

> The range concept defines the requirements of a type that allows iteration over its elements by providing an iterator and sentinel that denote the elements of the range.
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>   concept range =
>     requires(T& t) {
>       ranges::begin(t); // sometimes equality-preserving
>       ranges::end(t);
>     };
> ```

And input_iterator is:

> The input_­iterator concept defines requirements for a type whose
> referenced values can be read (from the requirement for
> indirectly_­readable ([iterator.concept.readable])) and which can be
> both pre- and post-incremented. [Note 1: Unlike the Cpp17InputIterator
> requirements ([input.iterators]), the input_­iterator concept does not
> need equality comparison since iterators are typically compared to
> sentinels. — end note]
>
> ```
> template<class I>
>   concept input_­iterator =
>     input_­or_­output_­iterator<I> &&
>     indirectly_­readable<I> &&
>     requires { typename ITER_CONCEPT(I); } &&
>     derived_­from<ITER_CONCEPT(I), input_iterator_tag>;
> ```

You can go read the specs for the dependee concepts, functions and traits for exact details.

> how this feature is supported by my own custom container?

In short: By conforming to the concepts shown above.

In medium: Provide member functions `begin` and `end` of which former should return an input iterator and latter should return a compatible sentinel type (which may be same or different from the iterator type). The end sentinel should be reachable from the beginning and represents one past the last element of the range.

In general, I recommend looking at API of standard containers to find out what members they provide and how they work. Copy the design to your custom containers.

---

Quotes are from the latest standard draft.

Comment: *"Quotes are from the latest standard draft."*. That sentence would then be outdated :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 It will be :) the answer is timestamped though, so there should be no mystery about which draft will have been the latest at the time of writing.